# Change text on same CLI line Python

Tags: python, curl, command-line-interface

Like how some command line utilities are able to change text on a line without making a new line (like curl).  How can I do that in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that the print statement ends with a carriage return and not a newline character.  For python 2.6+, you can use this really silly example to see.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sys

print(".", end="\r")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
print("..", end="\r")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
print("...")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Note:  when forcing the end of the print statement, you need to flush the stdout to force it to show.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sys.stdout.write` with "\r"(puts back the cursor to the starting of line)

demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import time
>>> while True:
...     sys.stdout.write("\r"+ str(i))
...     time.sleep(1)
...     i+=1
...
```